# How to wait for async method to return?

Tags: c#, mvvm, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to create an app which uses single sign on with live connect and registers the user automatically based on his live connect information.

Right when my application starts I call my LiveConnectViewModel and call those two functions:

```
        public async void AuthInitialize() 
    {
        string[] scopes = new[] { "wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.photos", "wl.emails", "wl.skydrive" };

        liveAuthClient = new LiveAuthClient();
        LiveLoginResult liveLoginResult = await liveAuthClient.InitializeAsync(scopes);

        if (liveLoginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            App.Session = liveLoginResult.Session;
        }
        else 
        {
            liveLoginResult = await liveAuthClient.LoginAsync(scopes);
            App.Session = liveLoginResult.Session;
        }
        await LoadProfileAsync();
    }

    public async Task LoadProfileAsync() 
    {
        LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(App.Session);
        LiveOperationResult liveOperationResult = await client.GetAsync("me");
        LiveOperationResult liveOperationResultPicture = await client.GetAsync("me/picture");
        dynamic dynResult = liveOperationResult.Result;
        dynResult.picture = liveOperationResultPicture.Result;
        User currentUser = await UserViewModel.findOrCreateUserAsync(dynResult);
        App.currentUser = currentUser;
    }
```

Right after that another method is invoked when the splash screen disappeared and my View comes up.

This execute that code:

```
        public ProfilePageViewModel()
    {
        this.CurrentUser = App.currentUser;
    }
```

Now my overall problem is the timing here. When I debug my application I can see that my LiveConnectViewModel gets called first and makes the initial connect, then the LoadProfileAsync gets executed until my program reaches the first await statement.

Immediately when reaching this point my application stops working on this call and goes on. Now when it comes to my ProfilePageViewModel and it should set my "CurrentUser" Property the await still didn't returned my User to my App.CurrentUser Property which is why it says it's null.

Normally I would just wait until the App.CurrentUser Property is set to something else than null, but I can't get rid of the strange feeling that I either missed to implement the MVVM Pattern right or that I did something extremely wrong with await and async...

Can anyone help me clarify this behavior?

Comment: Remove the `await` from in front of the call to LoadProfileAsync(); The `await`ing is already being done inside LoadProfileAsync().

Comment: Or vice-versa, if that suits your business need more appropriately. There is no need to await twice, ad doing so only confuses matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [avoid `async void`, as I describe in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Once you make `AuthInitializeAsync` return `Task` instead of `void`, then you can `await` it before creating your view model.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your answer. I already read your MSDN article in another post here on stackoverflow. My problem is, if I would change the return type to Task I could not call this function correctly in my constructor (which is what I'm actually doing). Is there any way to make this still work in my constructor?

Comment: I have a blog entry on [`async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). In my MVVM projects I follow the VM-first pattern with `async` factory methods. But if you're using an IoC or V-first pattern then you'll need to use the Async Initialization Pattern as described on my blog.